# XML Document Validation Error targetNamespace parameter

Tags: c#, xml

I have a schema with the following attributes:

```
<xs:schema id="FooFile"  
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"  
    targetNamespace="http://Foostandards.com"    
    elementFormDefault="qualified"    
    xmlns="http://Foostandards.com">
```

I have an XDocument constructor with the following attributes on the root tag (FooFile).

```
XDocument Foo2Xml = new XDocument(
    new XDeclaration("1.0", "utf-8", "yes"),
    new XComment("Foo2 file specifications implemented in xml"),
        new XElement("FooFile",
        new XAttribute(XNamespace.Xmlns + "xsi", "http://Foostandards.com"),
        new XAttribute(xsi + "schemaLocation", "http://Foostandards.com FooFile.xsd"), etc
```

I get the following error logged when I run the XDocument Validate method:

> "The targetNamespace parameter '' should be the same value as the
>   targetNamespace 'http://Foostandards.com' of the schema."

I have the targetNamespace parameter in the Schema and I can't find info that tells me that it even belongs in the XML document attributes (or how to code it).

Comment: Does your XML actually have the characters `\"` in it? If not, then please remove them from your post.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I figured it out. The error had nothing to do with the schema or the XDocument parameters. It was the Add method to the SchemaSet object that had a null value for the targetNamespace parameter.

My code:

```
XmlSchemaSet schemas = new XmlSchemaSet();
schemas.Add("", XmlReader.Create(new StringReader(xsd)));
```

Where xsd is a string representation of my schema. Note the "" as the first parameter of the Add method.

Code should have been:

```
XmlSchemaSet schemas = new XmlSchemaSet();
schemas.Add("http://Foostandards.com", XmlReader.Create(new StringReader(xsd)));
```

Answer (score 0):

While adding the XmlSchemaSet, we have to put the "targetNamespace" from the XSD file. Here is the below line of code.

**XSD file:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:tns="XXX" elementFormDefault="qualified" 
       targetNamespace="XXX" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
```

**C# Code:**

```
var schema = new XmlSchemaSet();
schema.Add("XXX", "XSD file path");
```

Where **XXX** : targetNamespace from XSD file

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem only after I added more than one XSD files into the XmlSchemaSet object.  It is strange that the VB console app seemed to work fine but in my ASP.NET app it threw an odd error stating the root element was not declared.  Some other forum threads suggested to add the targetNamespace and the associated xmlns attributes in the XSD file.  After adding those attributes to all my XSD files, I still ran into the same problem until I saw this forum describing exactly issue of having a "" in the first parameter when adding XSD into the XmlSchemaSet object.  By adding that parameter matching the targetNamespace in my XSD file, the exception was cleared.

Comment: How is this answer any different from the accepted answer?

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31012583)

Comment: I just found out that adding targetNamespace to the XML schema is also wrong if the XML file does not use the namespace.  So the acceptable answer only worked in cases where the XML data files contain the same namespace matching the one declared in the targetNamespace.  If you XML data file does not use any name space, just leave the targetNamespace out and use a empty string in to the first parameter. 
 You can pick your best answer now without further debate.

Answer (score 0):

Use `null` for the `targetNamespace` property — according to [`Add` method documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.schema.xmlschemaset.add?view=netframework-4.8#system-xml-schema-xmlschemaset-add(system-string-system-xml-xmlreader)) — the first parameter should be: *The schema `targetNamespace` property, or `null` to use the `targetNamespace` specified in the schema.*

So, the code from your answer could be written shortly this way:

```
XmlSchemaSet schemas = new XmlSchemaSet();
schemas.Add(null, XmlReader.Create(new StringReader(xsd)));
```